# Use of 'r0, lsr #32' in the return 'sub pc,lr,r0, lsr #32' with mmu/cache on

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mmu

The question is related to a piece of bootstrap code which you can find in the [`__common_mmu_cache_on`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S#L758).

```
1:              mcr     p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0   @ load control register
                mrc     p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0   @ and read it back to
                sub     pc, lr, r0, lsr #32     @ properly flush pipeline
```

The first instruction turns the mmu on.

Due to 3-stage pipeline, the next two instructions may have been pre-fetched.  So I wonder if `sub pc, lr, r0, lsr #32` is treated as two separate instructions?
If not, why not rewrite it into `sub pc, lr` since `r0, lsr, #32` does nothing.

Comment: I think 'mov pc, lr' will do the job. Why don't you try this out?

Comment: Ah, now I see. The author is trying to prevent the instructions from being executed at the same time. Due to the RAW dependency between the second and third instruction, they cannot be executed simultaneously. That's probably what the author intended.

Comment: This looks rather like some microarchitectural hack left over from ancient ARMv3/ARMv4 days before barrier operations were in any way standardised. Note in contrast how `__armv7_mmu_cache_on` just uses ISBs in the equivalent place.

Answer (score 0):

[Notlike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156750/notlikethat) that and [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021504/jake-alquimista-lee) have given you most of the answer.

> The author is trying to prevent the instructions from being executed at the same time. Due to the RAW dependency between the second and third instruction, they cannot be executed simultaneously. That's probably what the author intended. <sup>Jake</sup>

Right, it is a synchronization instruction of sorts.

> Note in contrast how `__armv7_mmu_cache_on` just uses ISBs in the equivalent place. <sup>Notlikethat</sup>

Also correct, but the `__armv7_mmu_cache_on` will have figured out what CPU we are running on.  This code (in head.S) is running on ARMv4-v5.  The `ISB` would fault on an ARMv4-v5.  A synthetic data dependency is used in lieu of an `ISB` so the code may execute on these ARM CPUs.

> So i wonder if `sub pc, lr, r0, lsr #32` is treated as two separate instructions? If not, why not rewrite it into `sub pc, lr` since `r0, lsr, #32` does nothing?

You are correct that the `r0, lsr #32` does nothing to calculating the return address.  Due to the data dependency, the CPU may not pre-determine the return address from the `lr` and prefetch the return code before the `mcr` has turned the MMU on.  It is effectively functioning as an `ISB` type instruction (but it can be *consumed* by an ARMv4 CPU).
The code is called from `armv4_mmu_cache_on` and `__fa526_cache_on`.  On all ARM CPUs, the `mcr` instruction may complete before the *co-processor* has actually made the code **active**.  So the CPU may have *issued* the turn on MMU/Cache, but this may not be in effect for a few CPU cycles.  Often people put `NOPs` in this code path, but this is fewer instructions.

Comment: I believe the real critical instruction being guarded against is the `mov pc, r12`.  I am pretty sure the MMU map is *virt==phys*, with a code duplicate at the *r12 destination* address.  If the MMU is not on by the time this instruction executes, we will die.  Also google *SA1100 dance of death*.  This was an MMU transtion in the original boot code from DEC.